# Objective-C + Cpp rvalues and arrays

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I need create array:

```
const UInt8 *pixels[3] = { yuvFrame.luma.bytes, yuvFrame.chromaB.bytes, yuvFrame.chromaR.bytes };
```

But Xcode show me error:

```
Cannot initialize an array element of type 'const UInt8 *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') with an rvalue of type 'const void *'
```

I am mixing C++ code with Objective-C. So how can I fix this? I need this const UInt8 *pixels[3]. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following initialization

```
const UInt8 *pixels[3] = 
{ 
    ( const UInt8 * )yuvFrame.luma.bytes, 
    ( const UInt8 * )yuvFrame.chromaB.bytes, 
    ( const UInt8 * )yuvFrame.chromaR.bytes 
};
```

In C++ there is no implicit conversion from a pointer of type `void *` to a pointer to an object of any other type.